# Dialogflow how to store querystring/conversation to a parameter?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am building a chatbot for our IT Support team.
We are integrating the bot with Jira Service Desk to create the ticket from the conversation with user.

Here is the flow

1. User contacts IT support by using the web chat saying that they would like to report an issue
2. Bot will ask for the user's email address to check if the user has valid support contract
3. In a conversation with the user, bot will determine the severity of the issue
4. Bot calls JSD Api to create ticket in the fulfillment

For step 4 above, to create a JSD ticket we want to pass the summary and description of the issue.

How can I store the conversation/querystring (not related to any entity but whole conversation)  as the summary/description to an intent parameter?

Can I set a parameter value from webhook?

Answer (score 0):

What is probably easier is to save anything you want (what the user says, any parts of it, etc) in a [context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts) parameter from your webhook. This will be carried across all rounds of your conversation, as long as the lifespan counter on the context doesn't decrement to 0. You can update this context parameter each round through your fulfillment webhook.

Comment: Hi Prisoner, thanks for your response. What I want to is to save a whole conversation in a parameter not only the highlighted one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "highlighted", but I've updated my answer to try and clarify.